# Not able to run Google Apis-explore for Cloud Natural Language

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-nl

Per docs, it seems it should be handled.  Not sure if there is anything else needed.

[Apis-explore](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/language/v1/language.documents.analyzeSentiment?fields=documentSentiment%252Clanguage%252Csentences&_h=1&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522document%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522content%2522%253A%20%2522Google%252C%20headquartered%20in%20Mountain%20View%252C%20unveiled%20the%20new%20Android%20phone%20at%20the%20Consumer%20Electronic%20Show.%20%20Sundar%20Pichai%20said%20in%20his%20keynote%20that%20users%20love%20their%20new%20Android%20phones.%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522language%2522%253A%20%2522en%2522%250A%20%20%257D%250A%257D&)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @John!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/documents/analyzeSentiment), it looks like you also need to specify a `type`.

[Example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/language/v1/language.documents.analyzeSentiment?_h=4&resource=%257B%250A++%2522document%2522%253A+%250A++%257B%250A++++%2522content%2522%253A+%2522Hello+world%2522%252C%250A++++%2522type%2522%253A+%2522PLAIN_TEXT%2522%250A++%257D%250A%257D&)